# issue with sscanf

Tags: matlab, scanf

I'm having issue with getting what I want from `sscanf`;

e.g. getting varname, year, month, day from a filename;

```
filename = 'stn2014021412598cjgafe.cnv'

format = '%3s%4d%2d%2d%5d%*10s'; 
test = sscanf(filename,format);
```

and I get the result:

```
 test =

     115
     116
     110
    2014
       2
      14
   12598
```

but what I want is the

```
varname = 'stn'
year = 2014
month = 2
day = 14
```

and then record or not the 5 digits

```
 num = 12598
```

and skip everything else.

However, I have no understanding on why I get those 3 numbers 115, 116, 110.

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those first three values are the character codes for `'s'`, `'t'` and `'n'`.  The [`sscanf` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) explains why it comes out this way for your `format` specifier.

> Mixing character and numeric conversion specifications causes the
>       resulting matrix to be numeric and any characters read to show up 
>       as their numeric values, one character per MATLAB matrix element.

In other words:

```
>> char(test(1:3))'
ans =
stn
```

---

An easier solution is probably [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) since it stores the components in a cell array, allowing different types:

```
>> C = textscan(filename,format)
C = 
    {1x1 cell}    [2014]    [2]    [14]    [12598]
>> C{1}
ans = 
    'stn'
```

Comment: excellent!! thanks so much! that makes much more sense to me now!